# Is this safe to do with a mysql database?

Tags: mysql

I have a table called DATA
In this table the first column is UUID
In this table the second column is name
and that's it.

Now, I currently have 1,057 uuid/name in my DATA table.
I also have a list of 200 uuids in a text file on my computer.

Is it safe to run 200 queries to return the names associated with my 200 uuids?

If I wanted to do this multiple times say every minute would I run into any problems?

How long would it take if this is possible?

Comment: Databases were designed to run queries, many of them, quickly.  The exact answer to your question depends on how often you plan to do this, what resources your database/computer have, etc.  If you plan to do this very often, one optimization might be to bring those 200 UUIDs into MySQL in the form of some sort of table.  Then, you could just do a join to your `DATA` table, possibly even using an index.

Comment: Why? Is the text file really going to change every minute?

Answer (score 0):

Its always best to keep data in DB for faster processing, instead of reading from file system everytime.

Now, lets consider you still insist those 200 UUIDs in file inside of in DB. I suggest, you can best handle by using a intermediate cache that stores those 200 UUIds. This prevents text file reading every five minutes, instead reads based on cache time out period.

Answer (score 0):

Although 200 queries is nothing to a well indexed database, here's some better options than using a text file to run queries every minute.

First, make sure that UUID column is indexed. This will make the queries O(1) rather than having to scan the whole table each time.

Then rather than doing a query for each UUID, you can do a single query with a big IN clause.

```
SELECT whatever
FROM data
WHERE id IN (list, of, uuids, ...)
```

Finally rather than having a big text file, you can put your UUIDs of interest into their own table and join against it. This gives you all the benefits of concurrency that a database brings, and all your data is in one place.

```
INSERT INTO users_of_interest
    (id)
    VALUES (...), (...), (...), ...

SELECT users.*
FROM users_of_interest
JOIN users ON users_of_interest.id = users.id
```

Then you can insert and delete from users_of_interest as the list changes. Be sure to do it in a transaction to avoid other people from also making changes while you are.